# How to troubleshoot: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.afAuth.authState.take is not a function?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework

I keep trying to open this page on my Ionic App, but everytime I do so, I receive the following error:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.afAuth.authState.take is not a function

It's very frustrating because it was working before! I'm at loss at how to fix this error. I imported "take" from rxjs/operators, then from rxjs/add/operator/take... Nothing is working.

The following is my TS and HTMl, respectively.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

//Firebase imports
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from '@angular/fire/database';

//Model import
import { list } from '../../models/list.interface';

//Pages import
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { take } from 'rxjs/add/operator/take';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-add-list',
  templateUrl: 'add-list.html',
})
export class AddListPage implements OnInit{

  list = {} as list;
  newListRef$: AngularFireList<list[]>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams, 
    private db: AngularFireDatabase,
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.afAuth.authState.take(1).subscribe(auth => {
      this.newListRef$ = this.db.list('list/'+auth.uid+'/');
    });
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad AddEventPage');
  }
  
  createNewList1(list: list) {
      this.newListRef$.push({
        name: this.list.name,
        color: this.list.color
      });
      this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
    }
  
}
```

```html
<ion-header no-border>
    <button clear id="close" ion-button navPop><ion-icon name="close"></ion-icon></button>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>

    <div class="title"><p>Add New List</p></div>
    
    <div class="list">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label color="secondary" stacked>List Name</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="list.name"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label color="secondary" stacked>Color</ion-label>
        <ion-select interface="popover" [(ngModel)]="list.color">
            <ion-option value="#89adbb">Pewter Blue</ion-option>
            <ion-option value="#496cbf">Queen Blue</ion-option>
            <ion-option value="#a7545b">Middle Red</ion-option>
            <ion-option value="#e6927e">Dark Salmon</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
    </div>
    
    <div class="button"><button ion-button (click)="createNewList1(list)">ADD LIST</button></div>
</ion-content>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Did you update RxJS recently ? What is your RxJS version ?

Comment: @ibenjelloun my RXJS version: 6.4.1. I believe that's the latest version?

Comment: According to the change log, the latest version is 6.3.3 : https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md . You can also see version history on npmjs.com : https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs

Comment: Hi @ibenjelloun, it turns out the RxJS version was not the issue here. If you would like to see the solution, I have posted an answer. .take() was just not applicable to the authState property. Thank you for your attempt!

Answer (score 0):

The property *authState* in *this.afAuth.authState.take(1).subscribe()* does not require a *.take()* method. So, essentially, *.take()* is not applicable to *authState*. Because of this, the error was returning that it was not a valid function. Makes sense!

Comment: You will probably have to dug deeper to understand whats happening. `authState` is an `Observable`, you can subscribe directly to the `Observable` or make some changes using operators (like 'take') before subscribing. Starting from the version 6 of RxJS the syntax has changed. Instead of `observable.take(1)` the new syntax is `observable.pipe(take(1))` also the imports are not the same. Removing the `take` will avoid the compilation error but the code would not have the same behavior.

Comment: @ibenjelloun, that's very interesting. I assumed that it worked because the compilation error did not take place and the function worked (it pushed the new info to Firebase Database correctly).